# I am getting an error message using maven in eclipse in pom.xml file .Cannot access defaults field of properties

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>in.movie.review</groupId>
  <artifactId>MovieReview</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MovieReview Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
      <java.version>11</java.version>
      <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
      
  </properties>
```

I am working on maven project.But i am getting an error my first line of pom.xml.I have JDK 11 working on eclipse(Only can use eclipse).Please help me with a solution.

ERROR

Cannot access defaults field of Properties  pom.xml /MovieReview    line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please include the exact, entire error message.

Comment: i updated my question.Can you check now

Comment: My first guess would be the 4.5 yr old version of `maven-jar-plugin`, have you tried a recent one?

Comment: no i did not tried it.can share the reference